# Can relative positioning be used within flexboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, flexbox

[Image showing overview of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SSEd.png)

I'm making modular row/column layout with variable combinations of rows in columns in rows etc. I'm using the *flex* property to make these elements fit nicely on the page.

CSS:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}
.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle showing the effect I'm going for](https://jsfiddle.net/a2u5dsm5/). Note that the columns are proportionally sized to their contents.

However, I'm also using *canvas* elements, and to achieve multiple drawing layers I'm stacking them like so:

CSS:

```
.canvasarea {
    position: relative;
}
.canvasarea canvas {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle showing this effect](https://jsfiddle.net/y6kLc4tg/).

When I try to combine these effects, however, I get [this unexpected result (fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/jp1cyevc/1/). It now sets the column width to 50% of the screen regardless of the child elements.

I've tried every *flex* and *position* option I could find but can't seem to put these two effects together. Is this possible to do like this, or am I breaking *flex* by my use of *relative*? I'd appreciate any tips, I'm still new to CSS.

Comment: In the 3rd example, you are using `flex: 50%;`, why so?

Comment: @Abinthaha Ah good catch--the example I initially used specified `flex: 50%;` but after reading I realized that 50% was arbitrary, it can be any positive number and function the same (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that setting `min-width` to the width of the widest element (in this case my canvas) [achieved the desired effect](https://i.imgur.com/jdZGpXS.gifv).

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <div style="min-width:300px" class ="canvasarea">
        <canvas id="cvs1back"></canvas>
        <canvas id="cvs1front"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <span>Some other text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div style="min-width:100px" class ="canvasarea">
        <canvas id="cvs2back"></canvas>
        <canvas id="cvs2front"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex: 1;
}

.canvasarea {
  position: relative;
}
.canvasarea canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
```

JS:

```
var canvas1size = 300;
var canvas1b = document.getElementById("cvs1back");
canvas1b.height = canvas1size;
canvas1b.width = canvas1size;
var ctx1b = canvas1b.getContext("2d");
ctx1b.fillStyle = "red";
ctx1b.fillRect(0, 0, canvas1b.width, canvas1b.height);

var canvas1f = document.getElementById("cvs1front");
canvas1f.height = canvas1size;
canvas1f.width = canvas1size;
var ctx1f = canvas1f.getContext("2d");
ctx1f.beginPath();
ctx1f.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx1f.moveTo(canvas1size,0);
ctx1f.lineTo(0,canvas1size);
ctx1f.stroke();

canvas2size = 100;
var canvas2b = document.getElementById("cvs2back");
canvas2b.height = canvas2size;
canvas2b.width = canvas2size;
var ctx2b = canvas2b.getContext("2d");
ctx2b.fillStyle = "gray";
ctx2b.fillRect(0, 0, canvas2b.width, canvas2b.height);

var canvas2f = document.getElementById("cvs2front");
canvas2f.height = canvas2size;
canvas2f.width = canvas2size;
var ctx2f = canvas2f.getContext("2d");
ctx2f.beginPath();
ctx2f.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx2f.moveTo(0,0);
ctx2f.lineTo(canvas2size,canvas2size);
ctx2f.stroke();
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jp1cyevc/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Set `flex: 1` to `.canvasarea` to fit the space available in flex container and `max-width: 100%` to canvas element to prevent overflow:

```js
var canvas1b = document.getElementById("cvs1back");
canvas1b.height = 400;
canvas1b.width = 400;
var ctx1b = canvas1b.getContext("2d");
ctx1b.fillStyle = "red";
ctx1b.fillRect(0, 0, canvas1b.width, canvas1b.height);

var canvas1f = document.getElementById("cvs1front");
canvas1f.height = 400;
canvas1f.width = 400;
var ctx1f = canvas1f.getContext("2d");
ctx1f.beginPath();
ctx1f.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx1f.lineTo(0, 0);
ctx1f.stroke();

var canvas2b = document.getElementById("cvs2back");
canvas2b.height = 400;
canvas2b.width = 400;
var ctx2b = canvas2b.getContext("2d");
ctx2b.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx2b.fillRect(0, 0, canvas2b.width, canvas2b.height);

var canvas2f = document.getElementById("cvs2front");
canvas2f.height = 400;
canvas2f.width = 400;
var ctx2f = canvas2f.getContext("2d");
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
}

.canvasarea {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
}

.canvasarea canvas {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
}

span {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="canvasarea">
      <canvas id="cvs1back"></canvas>
      <canvas id="cvs1front"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="row">
      <span>Some other text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="canvasarea">
        <canvas id="cvs2back"></canvas>
        <canvas id="cvs2front"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aha! This looks great, though it still enforces the column split to be at 50% of the width. In my first linked fiddle, the flex allows the first column to operate at full width (400px in this example) while the screen is small. Is this reproducible?

Comment: @mirrorcoloured you can use media queries to adjust how elements are layered out on the smaller screens - `@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}`. Assuming this is what you are after, if not, please correct me.

Comment: In [this example](https://i.imgur.com/xozeuvM.gifv) is my desired behavior, while currently it looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/Iowgc4V.gifv). It seems to me that my two columns are always each taking up 50% of the available width, but I would like them to only be as wide as they need to be (as in the first example). [Fiddle with current code](https://jsfiddle.net/jp1cyevc/4/)